# How do I respond to a resize event in my custom grid control?

Tags: delphi

I am new to Delphi and I'm building a custom control derived from TStringGrid. I need access to the OnResize event handler. How do I get access to it? TStringGrid's parent has a OnResize event

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Publish the `OnResize` event, which is protected by default in `TControl`.

---

In an own descendant, you should not use the event itself, but rather the method that triggers the event. Doing it that way will give the users of your component the opportunity to implement an own event handler.

Override the Resize method:

```
type
  TMyGrid = class(TStringGrid)
  protected
    procedure Resize; override;
  published
    property OnResize;
  end;

{ TMyGrid }

procedure TMyGrid.Resize;
begin
  // Here your code that has to be run before the OnResize event is to be fired
  inherited Resize; // < This fires the OnResize event
  // Here your code that has to be run after the OnResize event has fired
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was so obvious but somehow I missed it.

Comment: When used in virtual methods, you can just use the **inherited** reserved word alone to invoke the ancestor method without the name of the method itself.

Comment: @jachguate I certainly know, and I néver use it: the benefit from being able to ctrl-click to the ancestor implementation outweighs the little bit extra effort by far! Plus it helps distinguish methods from message handlers.

Comment: Agreed, it is sloppy work for any component to use its own published event to catch and handle - because it limits what the end-use can do. If the component assigns its own event handler to its own event, then an external implementation of this component assigns their own handler to this event, this replaces the event handler of the component. Catching the event call a step before the actual event is called is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Overriding Resize has a problem: the event will be called not only when the grid is actually resized **but also when you change the RowCount**.

In one program I needed to add/delete rows to grid as the user resized the grid. 
In other words I had to keep the grid filled with rows/data. However, data was not accessible while I was adding/deleting rows.

So, I used this:

```
protected
   procedure WMSize(var Msg: TWMSize); message WM_SIZE;
   .....

Implementation

procedure TMyGrid.WMSize(var Msg: TWMSize);      
begin
 inherited;
 if (csCreating in ControlState) then EXIT;                                                          { Maybe you also need this } { Don't let grid access data during design }
 ComputeRowCount;
 AssignDataToRows;
end;
```

Comment: This 'problem' comes from a change of the grid's _client_ space due to the (dis)appearance of the vertical scroll bar when in- or decreasing the row count. If your row count always fills up the entire visible grid, then I suggest to disable the vertical scroll bar. Otherwise, nice workaroud.

Comment: @NGLN - Thanks. The thing is that you don't know IF your rows will fill up the entire client area. I use the grid to display the content of a file (some kind of CSV, let's say). But in some cases that file will only have 1-2 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply place the TStringGrid inside a TPanel and align it to alClient, then use the published Resize event of the TPanel for any actions.

Comment: I tried resizing the panel with splitter, but the grid size stays the same even if panel is set to autoresize.