# How to implement custom TGraphicControl.OnResize?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Should I use `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED;`? (I havn't seen `CM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` or similar)

Will the TGraphicControl even be notified of this message (it has no Handle)? What is the correct method?

Thanks.

---

Just a thoght after accepting the answer:

Strangely or maybe intentionally `OnResize` fires even if only the Top/Left of the control position where changed:
in Delphi 7 `Resize` is called in `TControl.SetBounds` right after it calls `Perform(WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED)` even if no actual resize was made and the control was moved.
Is this by design?

Comment: If you are looking for a way how to have the resize event, then publishing the ready made `OnResize` event is the best choice. If you want to implement some extra logic into your component, override the `Resize` method. And don't you worry, even though `TGraphicControl` is not a window control, its ancestor `TControl` listens to many messages. That's because VCL dispatches the real system messages (or mimic them) through the `Perform` method. So even the way with `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` would work, but it's unecessarily low level.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I respond to a resize event in my custom grid control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727765/how-do-i-respond-to-a-resize-event-in-my-custom-grid-control)

Comment: @NGLN, It's not a duplicate directly: I knew how to deal with TCustomControl/TWinControl (grid control). My dilema was  specificly with TGraphicControl. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The OnResize Event is already implemented in TControl , it's just protected. To access it you just have to redeclare it for your component. You also might use a interposer class or a "Hack" class to access it. As example for a TImage:

using it for an own component:

```
TMycontrol=Class(TGraphicControl)
    published
    Property OnResize;
End;
```

using a interposer class:

```
type
  TImage=Class(ExtCtrls.TImage)
   Property OnResize; 
  End;

  TForm3 = class(TForm)
//....

procedure TForm3.MyResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Showmessage(Sender.ClassName)
end;


procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Image1.OnResize := MyResize;
  Image1.Width := 300;
end;
```

using a "hack" just in place:

```
implementation

{$R *.dfm}
Type THack=Class(TControl)
    Property OnResize;
End;

procedure TForm3.MyResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Showmessage(Sender.ClassName)
end;

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  THack(Image1).OnResize :=  MyResize;
  Image1.Width := 300;
end;
```

The event is triggered by the parentcontrol iterating the contained controls in TWinControl.AlignControls.

Comment: I overlooked the fact that OnResize is protected. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> ... `OnResize` fires even if ... no actual resize was made and the control was moved. Is this by design?

Yes. *Resize* does not necessarily only indicate a size change, but a change in any of the properties that defines its size, being: Left, Top, Width and Height.

> Will the `TGraphicControl` ...

Your question implies you are designing your own `TGraphicControl` descendant. Then you should not only publish the already present `OnResize` event, but also override the `Resize` method, as said by [TLama in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757347/how-to-implement-custom-tgraphiccontrol-onresize#comment31110117_20757347), and as [I answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14727765/757830).

Comment: Yes, but if to be picky: Left, Top does not define "Size". a real Window has different messages handlers for sizing/positioning. just saying :) +1